# How can i use kibana visualization query in elasticsearch dsl query?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, devops, elk

I am really happy to use kibana query to get data by using filtering like below.

```
Not why.keyword : "" and target.keyword :"Crystal Sunset Luxury Resort & Spa" and why.keyword : "Kum Plaj,Antalya" and rate >= 0.6
```

but i decide to use this query in elasticsearch query it throws an error. How can I convert above kibana query into simple elasticsearch query?

```
GET /hotelsimilarity-*/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "Not why.keyword : "" and target.keyword :"Crystal Sunset Luxury Resort & Spa" and why.keyword : "Kum Plaj,Antalya" and rate >= 0.6"
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "json_parse_exception",
        "reason": "Unexpected character ('\"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@23dd4c9a; line: 4, column: 43]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "json_parse_exception",
    "reason": "Unexpected character ('\"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@23dd4c9a; line: 4, column: 43]"
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your string by `\"` Or you can use `'` for your data with quotes.

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "Not why.keyword : '' and target.keyword :'Crystal Sunset Luxury Resort & Spa' and why.keyword : 'Kum Plaj,Antalya' and rate >= 0.6"
        }
    }
}
```

Error is mainly related to `improper JSON format` which caused by `mixing " in the query with " in the data`

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. it returns to me all Crystal etc.

Comment: @penguen there are two problems then. One is that query syntax error which is solved. But the other one is not mentioned in the question. Can you elaborate with sample doc also.